# Invoking a member function in a new-ed object with C++0x std::thread

Tags: c++, c++11, stdthread

I want to do something like this:

```
class A {
public:
    void a_start () {
        // somewhere in A: my_b = new B();
        std::thread t(my_b->b_start);   // won't compile
    }

private:
    B* my_b;
};

class B {
public:
    void b_start();
};
```

But it won't compile. I tried to look at http://accu.org/index.php/journals/1584 but it did not mention the case where the member function lies in a new-ed object. What is the correct syntax?

Comment: When you have a question about compilation errors, it's always a good idea to copy-paste those errors in the question. My guess here is that you need to put the definition of `B` before `A`, but as I don't know what errors you have it's just a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to accomplish this, such as using std::bind or using a trampoline member function, but I'd probably just use a lambda, like this:

```
std::thread t([&](){my_b->b_start();});
```

Comment: Random question: Does this close over `my_b` by reference, or does it close over `this` by reference and implicitly access the `my_b` member variable?

Comment: @Kevin I believe the `[&]` makes it close over any referenced variable used in the lambda by reference, so it's the same in this case as if we wrote `[&my_b]`. It is possible that I'm mistaken, but that's my understanding.

Comment: Yah know, I was writing a long comment exploring the technical difference between closing over `my_b` and `this->my_b` when I realized there is none. Oh well.

Comment: Another solution: `std::thread t(&B::b_start, my_b);` However, I also recommend lambda version...

Answer (score 0):

A pointer to a member function is not the same thing as a function. You can't pass one to `std::thread`. What you can do is declare a function that takes `my_b` as an argument and calls `b_start` on it, then pass the function and `my_b` to `std::thread`. Or, this being C++11, you can probably use a lambda:

```
void a_start() {
    std::thread t([](B* b){b->b_start();}, my_b);
}
```

(Note: I haven't tried compiling this myself).